# Htaccess - Modrewrite verify for 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

How Can i Comprobe for 404 not found?

This is my code php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$slug = "my-slugified-title-post-in-this-example"; // Slug is dinamic according to id

echo "This post is here!";
```

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/(.*?).html post.php?id=$1$slug=$2 [L,NC]
```

If the $slug in url is wrong, I want 404 error for:

```
http://mysite.com/posts/274/my-slugified-title-post-wrong-in-this-example.html //slug is wrong
```

This its Ok!

```
http://mysite.com/posts/274/my-slugified-title-post-in-this-example.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the slug is wrong, you have to compare that to the slug pulled from the id. So in your php script, you'll have something like:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$slug = "my-slugified-title-post-in-this-example"; // Slug is dinamic according to id

if ( $slug != $_GET['slug'] ) {   // slug is different
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit();
}

echo "This post is here!";
```